# Conditions to check whether a prime ramifies in a certain way

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $f = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n \geq 3$ with a root $\alpha$. We say that $p$ ramifies in a *powerful way* over $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ if the prime ideal decomposition of $(p)$ is given as $P_1^{e_1} \cdots P_l^{e_l}$ with $e_i \geq 2$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots, l$. Are there any simple congruence conditions on the coefficients of $f$ to check whether $p$ ramifies this way?

For example, if $f$ is an *Eisenstein polynomial* for $p$, meaning that $p$ divides $a_{n-1}, \cdots, a_0$ and $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$, then $p = (P)^n$ for some prime ideal $P$ in $K(\alpha)$. However, this condition is subtle. For instance of $f(x) = x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + 1$ then $f$ is not an Eisenstein polynomial but $f(x+1)$ is (this is the classic proof that the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible).

I am most interested in the case when $n = 4$ and $(p)$ splits into $(P)^4$ or $(P_1)^2(P_2)^2$.